# How to Keep the Status with Minimum Time in Line of Repeated Statuses

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Say I have status data from multiple builds that report different alarms at the time they are received:

```
build <- c(rep(11243, 6), rep(12640, 4))

message <- c(rep("High Temp", 2), rep("No Alarm", 2), rep("High Temp", 2), 
"Low Temp", rep("No Alarm", 2), "High Temp")

timeEntered <- c("2018-06-04 08:00:00", "2018-06-04 09:00:00", "2018-06-05 
08:00:00", "2018-06-06 08:00:00", "2018-06-06 09:00:00", "2018-06-07 08:08:00", 
"2017-05-23 12:45:00", "2017-05-23 13:00:00", "2017-05-24 12:30:00", "2017-05-24 12:45:00")

data <- data.frame(build, message, 
         timeEntered = as.POSIXct(timeEntered, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
build   message         timeEntered
11243 High Temp 2018-06-04 08:00:00
11243 High Temp 2018-06-04 09:00:00  
11243  No Alarm 2018-06-05 08:00:00
11243  No Alarm 2018-06-06 08:00:00
11243 High Temp 2018-06-06 09:00:00
11243 High Temp 2018-06-07 08:08:00
12640  Low Temp 2017-05-23 12:45:00
12640  No Alarm 2017-05-23 13:00:00
12640  No Alarm 2017-05-24 12:30:00
12640 High Temp 2017-05-24 12:45:00
```

I am looking to to get the minimum time of each message type by build while preserving the order I receive the messages.  For example, my end goal would be to have a data frame like this:

Output:

```
build   message         timeEntered
11243 High Temp 2018-06-04 08:00:00
11243  No Alarm 2018-06-05 08:00:00
11243 High Temp 2018-06-06 09:00:00
12640  Low Temp 2017-05-23 12:45:00
12640  No Alarm 2017-05-23 13:00:00
12640 High Temp 2017-05-24 12:45:00
```

Thank you ahead of time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data%>%
   group_by(s=cumsum(lag(message,default = message[1])!=message),build,message)%>%
   summarise(timeEntered=min(timeEntered))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   s, build [?]
      s build message   timeEntered        
  <int> <dbl> <chr>     <dttm>             
1     0 11243 High Temp 2018-06-04 08:00:00
2     1 11243 No Alarm  2018-06-05 08:00:00
3     2 11243 High Temp 2018-06-06 09:00:00
4     3 12640 Low Temp  2017-05-23 12:45:00
5     4 12640 No Alarm  2017-05-23 13:00:00
6     5 12640 High Temp 2017-05-24 12:45:00
```

Using Base R:

```
a=rle(data$message)
a$values=1:length(a$lengths)
aggregate(timeEntered~.,cbind(data,b=inverse.rle(a)),min)

  build   message b         timeEntered
1 11243 High Temp 1 2018-06-04 08:00:00
2 11243  No Alarm 2 2018-06-05 08:00:00
3 11243 High Temp 3 2018-06-06 09:00:00
4 12640  Low Temp 4 2017-05-23 12:45:00
5 12640  No Alarm 5 2017-05-23 13:00:00
6 12640 High Temp 6 2017-05-24 12:45:00
```

Comment: So, @Onyambu, `cumsum` is tracking how many non-matches in the lagged comparison have taken place since the first 'message' entered?

Comment: @Kyle sure sure. But you can use`rle` since that is the work of `rle`

Comment: That's true.  I didn't think about that, `rle` works wonders.  Thank you!